# Annot doesnt have action

Tags: itext, vb.net-2010

I'm trying to change all annotations link destination to fit page and also i need to validate the links.

This is the code i'm trying

```
Dim PdfReader As PdfReader
    'Dim myBookmarks As New List(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))()
    Dim pg As Integer

    PdfReader = New PdfReader("D:\\Annot_Testing.pdf")
    Dim PageCount As Integer = PdfReader.NumberOfPages
    For pg = 1 To PdfReader.NumberOfPages

        Dim PageDictionary As PdfDictionary = PdfReader.GetPageN(pg)
        Dim Annots As PdfArray = PageDictionary.GetAsArray(PdfName.ANNOTS)

        If (Annots Is Nothing) OrElse (Annots.Length = 0) Then
            Continue For
        End If

        ''//Loop through each annotation
        For Each A In Annots.ArrayList

            ''//I do not completely understand this but I think this turns an Indirect Reference into an actual object, but I could be wrong
            ''//Anyway, convert the itext-specific object as a generic PDF object
            Dim AnnotationDictionary = DirectCast(PdfReader.GetPdfObject(A), PdfDictionary)

            ''//Make sure this annotation has a link
            If Not AnnotationDictionary.Get(PdfName.SUBTYPE).Equals(PdfName.LINK) Then Continue For

            ''//Make sure this annotation has an ACTION
            If AnnotationDictionary.Get(PdfName.ACTION) Is Nothing Then Continue For

            ''//Get the ACTION for the current annotation
            Dim AnnotationAction = DirectCast(AnnotationDictionary.Get(PdfName.A), PdfDictionary)

            ''//Test if it is a named actions such as /FIRST, /LAST, etc
            If AnnotationAction.Get(PdfName.S).Equals(PdfName.NAMED) Then
                MsgBox("Yes named")

                ''//Otherwise see if its a GOTO page action
            ElseIf AnnotationAction.Get(PdfName.S).Equals(PdfName.PAGE) Then
                MsgBox("page")

            ElseIf AnnotationAction.Get(PdfName.S).Equals(PdfName.GOTOR) Then
                MsgBox("gotoR")

            ElseIf AnnotationAction.Get(PdfName.S).Equals(PdfName.GOTO) Then

                ''//Make sure that it has a destination
                If AnnotationAction.GetAsArray(PdfName.D) Is Nothing Then Continue For

                Dim AnnotationReferencedPage = PdfReader.GetPdfObject(DirectCast(AnnotationAction.GetAsArray(PdfName.D).ArrayList(0), PRIndirectReference))

                ''//Re-loop through all of the pages in the main document comparing them to this page
                For J = 1 To PageCount
                    If AnnotationReferencedPage.Equals(PdfReader.GetPageN(J)) Then
                        Trace.WriteLine(J)
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next
            ElseIf AnnotationAction.Get(PdfName.S).Equals(PdfName.URI) Then


            Else
                MsgBox("else type")
            End If
        Next



    Next
    'bookmarkGlobalSetting(myBookmarks)

    PdfReader.Close()
```

In the sample document attached having 3 annots, but its not showing action on it while reading via code, but its availed when seeing this in acrobat. Please suggest me on this..

please download from here... https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B72uT6TzR_cdWGczRkY3ZmNpeTg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You'll have to provide a link to the document, so that we can examine it. Maybe it's a JavaScript action. I'm not familiar with VB.Net, but unless I overlook an option, I don't see you checking for JavaScript.

Comment: Yes, please provide the PDF. Also, as the author of the code that you're using I can tell you there are many escapes built into via ` Continue For`, you should disable those escapes or at least have them `MsgBox` so that you know if/when they break out.

Comment: can you help me attach pdf file.., do we have any help document...

Comment: yes, i have attached the sample file, please help me to fix this..

Comment: Chris Haas, i knew that its breaking `If AnnotationDictionary.Get(PdfName.ACTION) Is Nothing Then Continue For` here, due to no action, but its availed while seeing via acrobat..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those annotations do not have any **A** action entry:

[image: RUPS screenshot of **Annots** of the sample PDF]

Your expectation to find an action with a link is wrong because it may alternatively have a destination, cf. section *12.5.6.5 Link Annotations* of [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf):

> A *link annotation* represents either a hypertext link to a destination elsewhere in the document (see 12.3.2, “Destinations”) or an action to be performed (12.6, “Actions”). Table 173 shows the annotation dictionary entries specific to this type of annotation.

Your code only deals with the latter type (with *an action to be performed*) and not the former (with *a hypertext link to a destination elsewhere in the document*).

Thus, you have to improve your code to also deal with the former type. You'll find details in *Table 173 – Additional entries specific to a link annotation* of [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf).

PS: I assume your

```
If AnnotationDictionary.Get(PdfName.ACTION) Is Nothing Then Continue For
```

should have been

```
If AnnotationDictionary.Get(PdfName.A) Is Nothing Then Continue For
```

Comment: And do we have any method to validate, whether its valid link or not..?

Comment: *can i get the page number where it designated to.* - youhave the **Page** object targeted  essentials, therefore, you need a mapping page object reference -> page number.

Comment: *do we have any method to validate, whether its valid link or not..?* - which kinds of validations do you wish?

Comment: i need to validate whether the designated page availed in the pdf or not.

Comment: _you need a mapping page object reference -> page number_, basically i need to set all destinations to fit page, will it be possible without page reference...? this page doesnt have other destinations, but i have an pdf like that, means fitR..

Comment: Look at *Table 151 – Destination syntax* in [ISO-32000](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf); you'll see that the page reference always is first. Thus, when exchanging the opening parameters, you can simply ignore the page reference.